# GWTTestCase - HTMLUnit - No permitted "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: gwt, junit, htmlunit, restlet

When running `GWTTestCase` that call an external Restful service with GWT (Using Restlet-GWT) the app throws the error below.

**Error:**

```
Jan 05, 2015 1:24:41 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl runSingleJob
SEVERE: Job run failed with unexpected RuntimeException: Wrapped java.lang.RuntimeException: No permitted "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.RuntimeException: No permitted "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1889)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest.doSend(XMLHttpRequest.java:681)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest.access$000(XMLHttpRequest.java:94)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest$1.run(XMLHttpRequest.java:603)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavascriptXMLHttpRequestJob.run(JavascriptXMLHttpRequestJob.java:36)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:328)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No permitted "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.
    ... 9 more
```

From my research this seems to be an issue that HTMLUnit would not allow to access Cross-domain, is there a work around with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the support of CORS to your application.

A support has been provided in 2.3 release of the Restlet framework (cf http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/introduction/whats-new/2.3).
If you are using the 2.2 release, and because we won't add this feature to 2.2, you can add the required classes in your own code manually (cf https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/2.3/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/service/CorsService.java, https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/2.3/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/engine/application/CorsFilter.java, and https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/2.3/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/engine/application/CorsResponseHelper.java).

Answer (score 3):

I was stumped by this very same error response but I am not able to refactor the Restlet framework into my client & server codebases.

A couple of tips for handling diagnosis of the problem.

1. use a proxy or inspect dev tool to record the exact headers within the request and response for both the OPTIONS and GET/POST pairs.
2. OPTIONS request header "Origin" must match response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" exactly. No wildcards. Perhaps write your response to just echo the request like:

   response.addHeader("Access-control-allow-origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
3. Your request header names must be fully enumerated within the OPTIONS "Access-control-request-headers" header value AND match the "Access-control-Allow-Headers" response header.

Note: that a mismatch in #3 will trigger the same error message as a mismatch in #2.